# CPU utilisation issue while adding INDEX to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, performance, load, cpu-usage, database-performance

A table having billions of rows. I'm using MySQL 5.7
When I'm trying to add an index to the table it takes very long time and it locks the table too.
As a result, many queries wait in queue and server load increases.

I don't understand while adding an index to a table is creates table lock which is metadata lock.
Can you please explain why is this happing and also provide a solution for the same.

CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `user_log` (
`id` bigint(14) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`latitude` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
`longitude` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
`created_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20000000000 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

ALTER COMMAND

```
ALTER TABLE `user_log` ADD INDEX (`user_id`, `created_date`);
```

Comment: Not all `ALTERs` are as fast as one would like.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE_TABLE` and the `ALTER` statement.

Comment: @RickJames Added create table and alter command

Comment: Check out `pt-online-schema-change` and `gh-ost`.  I don't know whether they will work in this specific case, but maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why mysql need lock table**
Firstly, there are lots of `DDL` operations in mysql, such as `alter table`, `drop table`...These statements differed from `DML` operations such as `insert`,`update`, `select`.The `DDL` operations will change table schema,while `DML` operations just effect rows.
Secondly, there are multiple well-known locks in innodb, such as row lock, next-key lock.But MetaData lock very few people knows.The `DDL` operations will acquire exclusive MetaData lock to guarantee data consistency, which will block `DML` operations.For what situation the `DDL` operations will leading to data exception without MetaData lock,you can reference [bug#989](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=989) .

**How to DDL without block**

Nowadays, mysql suport online ddl to do `DDL` operations without lock.
There are no magics in online ddl,which just create a new table with same structure, and operate `DDL` statement on new table,then rename new table with old table.

To add an index to a table without a lock resulting on UPDATE/ INSERT, the following statement format can be used:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX my_table__idx (my_column), ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
```

Comment: Aren't those the defaults for `ADD INDEX`?

Comment: I justed checking mysql documentation, I found that online ddl is default opition for ```ADD INDEX```.@RickJames Did  ```ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX my_table__idx (my_column), ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;``` fixing your problem and run faster?